# TableLayout addView doesn't work

Tags: android

I have a xml file of LinearLayout which includes a TableLayout, the later includes TableRows, So I want a new TableRow to be added programmatically when the app running.

So I wrote the following code using addView method but my code don't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout myRoot = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tbl_test);
    TableRow a =   new TableRow(this);
    a.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    myRoot.addView(a);   
}
  }
```

The xml file

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:orientation="vertical">


      <TableLayout 
      android:id="@+id/tbl_test"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#000000"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
      android:stretchColumns="1"
                                >

     <TableRow 
     android:id="@+id/tbr_test" 
     android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_margin="1dp">

    <TextView   android:layout_column="0" />
    <TextView   android:layout_column="1" />
    <TextView   android:layout_column="2" />
    <TextView  android:layout_column="3" />

     </TableRow>

     <TableRow
     android:background="#ffffff"
     android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="1dp">

     <TextView android:layout_column="0" />
     <TextView android:layout_column="1" />
     <Button/>
     <Button/>

     </TableRow>

     <TableRow
     android:background="#ffffff"
     android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
     android:paddingRight="2dp">

     <TextView android:layout_column="0" />
     <TextView  android:layout_column="1" />
     <Button/>
     <Button />

     </TableRow>

     <TableRow
     android:background="#ffffff"
     android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
     android:paddingRight="3dp">

     <TextView android:layout_column="0" />
     <TextView  android:layout_column="1" />
     <Button />
     <Button />

     </TableRow>

     <TableRow
     android:id="@+id/tbr" 
     android:background="#ffffff"
     android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
     android:paddingRight="4dp">

    <TextView  android:layout_column="0" />
    <TextView  android:layout_column="1" />
    <Button />
    <Button/>

    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`TableLayout.LayoutParams` is causing the issue. So You have to use `LayoutParams` Instead of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

So Change your this code

```
 TableRow a = new TableRow(this);
 a.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 myRoot.addView(a);
```

to this

```
TableRow a = new TableRow(this);
a.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
myRoot.addView(a);
```

and give some background color or add some Component  to see in the added `TableRow`.

Comment: @JavaFan What problem you have ocuure after adding this.

Comment: No problem but no new row added  might be because minimum api is set to 8? but I add this line  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

Comment: I should do something like this true  a.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);?

Comment: @JavaFan If you want to see the code is work or not just give the `BackgroundColor` to it.

Comment: @JavaFan add this way `Resources resource = context.getResources();
a.setBackgroundColor(resource.getColor(R.color.red)`.